# move backButton from default UINavigationbar to customNavigationbar in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In `viewWillAppear` i hide my `navigationController` and `navigationBar` like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
}
```

Then i added a `navigationBar` in my `Storyboard` and connected it to an `IBOutlet` in my `UIViewController` to customize it from IB.

Everything is working fine except i can not move default `backButton` from the original hidden `navigatioBar` to my new custom `navigationBar`.

**Question:**

Is there a way to move `backButton` from default `navigationBar` to this new custom `navigationBar`?**

Note: I don't want to add a customized back button.

Comment: Why are you adding a custom navigationBar when you already got a navigationBar that you are hiding?

Comment: @Sneak because my first viewcontroller got non-translucent navigationbar, and my second viewcontroller needs a translucent navigationbar. when you change isTranslucent on second viewcontroller you get a weird animation from pushing to second viewcontroller. so i needed a custom navigationbar to fix this

Comment: I see, and you tried to change isTranslucent in viewDidAppear / viewWillAppear without success?

Comment: @Sneak there is no way to change isTranslucent and get a fine animation from pushing a viewcontroller. i searched alot and only solution was to use a custom navigationbar. i set isTranslucent for my custom navigationbar in viewDidLoad

Comment: You really shouldnt try to access and modify the automatically created backButton that represents the previous UIViewController. You should create your own.

Comment: @Sneak thanks it looks like there is no way to do this and i should use customized navigationabar through all viewcontrollers

Comment: Yes, more work, but clean code and avoiding bad practices. :) GL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You'd need to create your own UIBarButtonItem

```
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(yourSelector))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem
```

Comment: looks like i should use customnavigaitonbar in all my viewcontrollers and use custom backbutton for navigaitonbars. thanks